# The definition of limits in "Real Mathematical Analysis" by Pugh doesn't make sense to me.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

At the beginning of Section 3 on p65, the text says the following:

> Let $M$ be a metric space and let $S$ be a subset of $M$. A point
>   $p\in M$ is a limit of $S$ if there exists a sequence $(p_n)$ in $S$
>   that converges to it.

This doesn't make sense to me because any point would have the sequence of infinite repetitions of that point "converging" to it and therefore be a limit point.

Other definitions that I read, like the one on wikipedia, state that a limit point is defined by having in every epsilon neighborhood around it at least one other point of the set. This second definition makes sense to me and doesn't seem to be equivalent to the first one at all because the first statement would be true for a singleton while the second one would be false. Am I misinterpreting the meaning of the definition or is it a mistake in the book?

Thanks!

Update:

As pointed out by @calum-gilhooley, there's a footnote that I should have read more carefully that actually addresses this ambiguity. Somehow I thought that the footnote was about something else but after reading some of the answers and the definition of adherence, it makes perfect sense. Apparently C. Pugh defines a limit as a point that *adheres* to the set and not as what is known as a limit point so there's no mistake on his part.

Apparently I'm too green to vote so thanks a lot for the great answers and comments!

Comment: None of the sequence members should equal the point $p$ under consideration. It should be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: The definition in the book is not the standard one. What they have defined can be called  a 'closure point' of $S$ rather then a limit point.

Comment: Different authors may use differing def'ns. And translations of a term may vary. Sometimes you need to make a mental adjustment for this when changing books.

Comment: "This doesn't make sense to me because any point would have the sequence of infinite repetitions of that point "converging" to it and therefore be a limit point. "  $S$ is a set and each element is distinct.  So a sequence *IN* $S$ can not have any duplicate elements.  If is $k\ne j$ and $\{p_n\}\subset S$ is an infinite sequence then $p_k \ne p_j$.

Comment: Ack!  Looks like I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the second edition of Pugh's book, but the first edition (2002) has exactly the wording you have quoted, plus a footnote:

> A limit of $S$ is also sometimes called a **limit point** of $S.$ Take care though: some mathematicians require that a limit point of $S$ be the limit of a sequence of *distinct* points of $S.$ They would say that a finite set has no limit points. We will *not* adopt their point of view. Another word used in this context, especially by the French, is "adherence." A point $p$ **adheres** to the set $S$ if and only if $p$ is a limit of $S.$ In more general circumstances, limits are defined using "nets" instead of sequences. You can read more about nets in graduate level topology books such as *Topology* by James Munkres.

I haven't come across Pugh's use of the term before, and I can't say I approve of it (there's more then enough ambiguity in mathematical terminology without adding to it), but at least he signposts the difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, so according to this definition every point of $S$ would be a limit of $S$. That being said, the definition is telling you what a point $p \in M$ needs to satisfy in order to be a limit of $S$. So you couldn't just take an infinite number of that point $p \in M$ to get a sequencce of elements in $S$ that converges to $p$, since it may be that $p \notin S$.

The equation that you say you are comfortable with can be shown to be equivalent to the condition given in Pugh's book as long as the space you are working in is First Countable, which every metric space is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming we are in a metric space throughout. If not the sequential descriptions may not work, and they ought to be reformulated.

The definition you are quoting calls "a limit" of $S$ what is often called a point *adherent* to $S$ (i.e. an element of the topological closure $\overline S$), whereas *limit point* of $S$ typically indicates a point $x$ such that there is a sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subseteq S\setminus\{x\}$ converging to $x$ (i.e. the derived set $S'$).

Whether or not this is intendend or not, I cannot tell because I don't own the book: you should be on the lookout for the possibility of a mistake (though it should really be a minor thing).

As far as I know it is also very common to call *a limit point* of a sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ any limit of a convergent subsequence. If we call $S=\{s_n\,:\, n\in\Bbb N\}$ the image set of the sequence, the limit points of the sequence are a set $T$ such that $S'\subseteq T\subseteq \overline S$. Namely, if we call $S_m=\{s_n\,:\, m\ge n\}$, we have that $T=\bigcap_{m\in\Bbb N}\overline S_m$.

Answer (score 0):

Pugh appears to have a different meaning of "limit" point than others do.

And according to Pugh's meaning.  If $p \in S$, even if $p$ is a singleton, the Pugh considered $p$ to be a limit point.

Most texts (as others have pointed out) would call the an "adherent point".

So Pugh's meaning of a limit point is:  $p \in S$ or $p$ is a conventional epsilon definition of a limit point.

===== Ack! Everything Below is Wrong  (but in my opinion *shouldn't* be) =====

$S$ is a set.  Each element is distinct.  So you can not have a sequence where two elements are equal. However, $S$ is unordered so you can pick the elements in the sequence in any order you want so long as they never repeat.  As a consequence, no finite set can have a limit point.

This is equivalent to the epsilon neighorhood definition.

........

Epsilon definition $\implies$ sequence definition.

Let $p$ be an epsilon definition of limit point.

Let $e_n = \frac 1n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.  By definition For each $e_n$ there is a point $p_n\in S$ so that $d(p,p_n) < e_n$.

By definition of convergence:  The sequence of this $p_n$ converge to $p$.  For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N= \frac 1\epsilon$ and if if $n >N$ then $d(p,p_n) < \frac 1n < \frac 1N = \epsilon$.

So $p$ is a sequence defined limit point.

......

Sequence definition of limit point $\implies$ epsilon defintion.

Let $p$ be a sequence defined limit point of $S$.

Then there exists a sequence $\{p_n\} \to p$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ then there is an $N$ so that $n > N$ implies $d(p,p_n) \epsilon$.  So the neighborhood $B_\epsilon (p) = \{x\in X| d(x,p) < \epsilon$ will contain a point, $p_k \in S; k\ge n$  as the $p_k$ are distinct some of them are not equal to $p$.

So $p$ is an epsilon defined limit point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=(0,\infty)\subset\mathbb R$. According to the definition, all elements of $S$ are (trivial) limit points. In addition, $0\notin S$ is a (non-trivial) limit point as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1n=0$.

The definition makes sense for the points of $M\setminus S$.